# How do I examine biasedness in nonlinear regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression, bias, unbiased-estimator

I have the nonlinear regression model $$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}+e^{\beta_2 x_{2i}}+u_i,\quad i=1,2,\ldots,n,$$ and the least squares assumptions are satisfied (see below). Let $\beta=(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2)$.

Given this model, I want to *examine* the bias of the [nonlinear least squares estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression#Regression_statistics) of $\beta$. This estimate is given by the global solution to the minimization problem $$\min_{\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2}\sum_i(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1 x_{1i}-e^{\beta_2 x_{2i}})^2.$$ The solution may be denoted by $\hat{\beta}=(\hat{\beta}_0,\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)$.

(One may note that the first order conditions to the minimization problem are

\begin{cases} 
   \sum_i(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1 x_{1i}-e^{\beta_2 x_{2i}})&=0;\\ \sum_i(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1 x_{1i}-e^{\beta_2 x_{2i}})x_{1i}&=0;\\ \sum_i(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1 x_{1i}-e^{\beta_2 x_{2i}})e^{\beta_2 x_{2i}}&=0;
  \end{cases}

and add to this that I do not think we can find a analytic solution to this equation system. Thus, we may have to use computer algorithms to solve the system above.)

Now, I have two questions regarding $\hat{\beta}$.

A. Firstly, how do I examine the bias $E(\hat{\beta}-\beta)$? (Expectation is taken componentwise.)

B. Secondly, is the bias equal to zero for the intercept and the coefficient on $x_{1i}$? I.e., is it true that $$E(\hat{\beta}-\beta)=(0,0,E(\hat{\beta}_2-\beta_2))?$$ For the first question, A, I am looking for a method of investigation; it may involve using e.g. MATLAB or Mathematica. For the second question, B, I am looking for a proof or a counterexample. (Question B may be viewed as a subquestion to A.)

I am interested in this for it is often said that nonlinear regression introduce bias into the statistics. References for this statement are several, e.g., the Wikipedia article in English on [nonlinear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression); page 51 in *Nonlinear Regression*, 2005, by G. A. F. Seber, C. J. Wild; Bias in Nonlinear Regression, Cook et al.,  *Biometrika* (1986), 73, 3, pp. 615-23; Bias in Nonlinear Estimation, M. J. Box, *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological)* (1971), 33, 2, pp. 171-201; and the blog post [Some Properties of Non-linear Least Squares](http://davegiles.blogspot.se/2012/10/some-properties-of-non-linear-least.html) by Dave Giles.

*Least squares assumptions.*

1. For all $i$, the error term $u_i$ has conditional mean zero given $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$, i.e. $E(u_i|x_{1i},x_{2i})=0$.
2. $(y_i,x_{1i},x_{2i})$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, are i.i.d. draws from their joint distribution.
3. Large outliers are unlikely, meaning that for each $i$, $y_i$, $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ have nonzero finite fourth moments.
4. There is no perfect multicollinearity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define
$$z\equiv{y}-e^{\beta_2 x_2}=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1+u$$
then given $\beta_2$, you can estimate $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ via OLS.
This trick is useful [computationally](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101895-how-do-i-solve-partitioned-or-separable-least-squares-problems-using-the-lsqcurvefit-function-within) to turn your problem into a *scalar* nonlinear optimization over $\beta_2$.

As OLS is unbiased,  any **bias** in the ***nonlinear* parameter** will be **inherited** by the ***linear* parameters**. That is, if $\beta_2$ is unbiased, then all parameters will be unbiased. But if not, then the linear parameters must *also* be biased. So in general the answer to your question B is **no**.

For your question A, numerical experiments would be a reasonable start. (Here the regime of interest would be where the range of $\beta_2x_2$ is "not too small", else the nonlinearity will be "linearized out".)

Note also that your references give some approximate formulas for estimating the bias.

---

Clarification: the optimization objective function (error) is identical when using the partitioned approach, i.e. 
$$E\big[\beta_{0:2}\big]=\tfrac{1}{2}\Big\|z\big[\beta_2\big]-\hat{y}_\mathrm{lin}\big[\beta_{0:1}\big]\Big\|^2$$
The "separable" approach works because for the linear sub-problem, OLS gives the *global* optimum (for a given $\beta_2$).

Comment: Informative answer! I have read about this method. However, I was asking about the properties of the nonlinear least squares (NLLS) estimate. Does your way of working with the problem coincide with finding the NLLS-estimate? Maybe my question is uninformed now, but I will read about separable nonlinear least squares problems tomorrow, thanks for the link! Regarding A, I guess Monte Carlo methods and bootstrapping works for experimentation? About your last comment:  Yeah, that is correct, and I have actually tried to investigate the bias using those articles today.

Comment: Yes "my way" corresponds to the nonlin-lsqr estimate. Note that it does not change the objective function, and in fact your 1st two "local optimum" conditions correspond to those for the linear-lsqr fit to $z$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to talk about whether $\hat{\beta}$ is biased, we need to have some concept of a true $\beta$. That is, we need to specify a data-generating process. So in order to make this problem tractable, let's assume that

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + e^{\beta_2 x_{i2}} + u_i$

and

$u_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Your estimator is asymptotically unbiased because it has the same
solution as a maximum likelihood problem, and MLE is asymptotically unbiased.

Here's the math:
\begin{align}
f(y_i | x_i; b, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-(y_i - b_0 - b_1 x_{i1} - e^{b_2 x_{i2}})^2 / 2 \sigma^2} \\
\end{align}
$
\log(LL(b, \sigma | y_1, \dots y_n, x_1, \dots x_n)) = 
-\frac{n}{2} \log(\sigma^2) - \sum_i (y_i - b_0 - b_1 x_{i1} - e^{b_2 x_{i2}})^2 / (2 \sigma^2)
$

You can check that the log-likelihood has the same first-order conditions for $b_0$, $b_1$, and $b_2$ as the least-squares problem you set up, so it has the same answer. (Solving this as an MLE problem also requires estimating $\sigma^2$, but the estimate of $\sigma^2$ doesn't affect the estimates of $\beta$.)

So it's asymptotically unbiased, but what about in finite samples? I'm not sure how to prove that. Here's a sketchy "proof by Matlab", where the first three components of "params" correspond to $\beta$ and the last corresponds to $\sigma^2$::

`b = [1, 1, 1];
sigma_squared = 1;
n = 100;
nIters = 10000;
rng(10317);
ll = @(y, x, b, n) sum((y - b(1) - b(2)*x(:, 1) - exp(b(3) * x(:, 2))).^2) / (2 * b(4)) + .5 * n* log(b(4));
params = zeros(niters, 4);
options = optimoptions(@fminunc, 'Algorithm', 'quasi-newton')
x = normrnd(0, 1, n(n_obs), 2);
mean_ = b(1) + x(:, 1) * b(2) + exp(x(:, 2) * b(3));
for ii = 1:niters
    y = mean_ + normrnd(0, sigma_squared, n(n_obs), 1);
    params(ii, :) = fminunc(@(b) ll(y, x, b, n(n_obs)), [1, 1, 1, 1], options);
end
E_b_hat = mean(params);
b_se = std(params) / (nIters - 1);
bias = E_b_hat - b;`

I get a near-zero and insignificant bias for $\hat{\beta}$. However, this only "proves" that $\hat{\beta}$ is unbiased for a particular value of $\beta$ and distribution of $u$ and $x$. This estimator might not be finite-sample unbiased in general.

(A general tip that doesn't apply here: When it's easy to prove biasedness in nonlinear least squares, it's often through invoking Jensen's Inequality. See [this reference](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/m-unbiased.pdf).)

Comment: (+1) Re "near-zero and insignificant bias:" One thing that struck me in examining this question is that even a tiny bit of bias in the estimate of $\beta_2$ can translate into relatively large errors in the contributions $\exp(\beta_2 x_2)$. It is clear that when $x_2$ has more than two unique values, then $\hat\beta_2$ must be biased.  Thus the focus of a good analysis ought to be on estimating the effect of the bias.

Comment: "It is clear that when $x_2$ has more than two unique values, then $\hat{\beta}_2$ must be biased." 

Why? It's not obvious to me.